# What is the default condition set to?

Tags: c#

I'm making my way through the documentation and came across this code and i want to know what '{0}' is for? and why the ',n' afterwards? I tinkered around and understand what happens if they're not there but i'd like to be able to word it in my head so can someone please explain what is happening?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int n = args.Length;
    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("No arguments");
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("One argument");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} arguments", n);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with "default conditions" - it's a format string accepted by `Console.WriteLine`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#Starting

Comment: Did you read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) or [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.8)? If you read them you should understand...

Comment: thanks, the order in which im supposed to go through the documentation is a bit hard to get so thank you

Comment: There really isn't an order you're supposed to go through in the documentation. It doesn't read like a book. You kinda just need to jump into what you need for a particular topic. Here, the `Console.WriteLine` would have been the place to start.

Comment: @CodeStranger So would you recommend i keep coding and only reference it when im stuck?

Comment: @TübaËs Sort of. Definitely reference it when stuck, but you might also familiarize yourself with certain pages when working with common types (i.e. knowing what the `String` class has available to it is invaluable). But it's hard to give a concrete recommendation because it's just not black and white. I will say that reading everything you possibly can in the docs is a waste of time. There's no way you'll retain that much info and level of detail, and won't be working with all of the types available anyway. There's just too much out there.